# Unable to commit folder using SVN Tortoise as it keeps on asking authentication

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, assembla

I have setup the SVN tortoise properly. I can easily update the files from the server but when I try to commit my changes it keeps on prompting for the authentication even I put the correct one. The same username and password works when I browse with assembla.com

I am using assembla file server. The prompt message says that it is a restricted area and the URL is https://subversion.assembla.com:443

Your suggestions are valuable. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm also using Assembla and have the same problem recently. It actually doesn't matter which password I use, still works! I guess they've done something wierd with their SVN servers. Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to TortoiseSVN -> settings -> Saved Data -> Press Clear All next to the Authentication Data.

Try to access your folder, when prompted for credentials please provide the same and press Remember. That should work!!

Comment: it does not work. I tried and it keeps on asking the authentication even I type correct. Any other suggestions please

Comment: If nothing works, update the latest source once and try restarting the machine. It should work with the above fix.

Comment: I already have it and also restarted nothing works @realspirituals.